# How to integrate awk parameters in awk range pattern

Tags: awk, regular-expression

I need to get something like this

```
#Batch Job - AB1234
texts
texts
texts
texts
texts
#--------
```

I used

```
awk '/#Batch Job.*AB1234/,/#--.*/' filename
```

and i went well.

But then when I tried to parameterize the AB1234, using this script, I failed.

```
BATCHJOBNAME=AB1234
awk -v batchjobname=$BATCHJOBNAME '
  /#Batch.*/ { f=1 ; m=0 ; res="" }
  f { res = res $0 ORS }
  f && /Job.*/ && index($2,batchjobname) > 0 { m=1 ;}
  /<#--.*>/ { f=0 ; if (m) print res ; }
 ' filename
```

Comment: Have you try to remove spaces on variable assignment? BATCHJOBNAME=AB1234

Comment: Just a typo in transposition. I edited it now thanks @Romeo

Comment: What about `awk -v batchjobname=AB1234 '$0~batchjobname,/#--.*/' filename` ?

Comment: I personally have problem to understand the logic and what you expect as result. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @FloHimself it's printing right but Im having an error

Comment: in the third line of awk script, use either `index($0,batchjobname)` (best) or ìndex($4,batchjobname)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```bash
BATCH=AB1234
awk -v batch="#Batch Job.*${BATCH}" '($0 ~ batch),/#--.*/' filename
```

Comment: It's good when AB1234 is hardcoded but when I use $BATCHJOBNAME, it is failing. I am getting my parameters from a .properties file so I cannot hardcode it

Comment: @PhilipMorris `awk -v batchjobname="#Batch Job.*$BATCHJOBNAME" ...`.  Just make sure to keep it a valid regexp.

Comment: I tried that. It failed

Comment: @PhilipMorris Try understanding it first.  Ok, I edited my answer.

Comment: I am having errors when I run it the second time. It is good when ran the first time. Why is that

Comment: That depends on what you're doing, and what errors you get.